# How do I transfer my data? I am giving my phone in exchange

Tags: data-transfer, device-migration

I have bought a Redmi Note 5 on Flipkart and I have a Micromax Canvas Nitro 2 with Android 4.0.4 which I am giving in exchange. How do I transfer my data without taking too long?

Comment: You've picked the right tag. Have you checked our [most frequented questions using it](/questions/tagged/data-transfer?sort=frequent)? Those [using the device-migration tag](/questions/tagged/device-migration) could also be of interest for you. You will find your question has already be answered; then please point to the correct post. If not, please [edit] your question and adjust it accordingly (what have you tried/checked and why didn't it work out).

Comment: +1 on the tag pick, nice catch @Izzy

Answer (score 0):

First of all this link should help you:
**https://support.google.com/android/answer/2819582?hl=en**

> There are many applications out there in Play Store. So, you can download and
>   save your Apps' data. And if you want to backup your storage files
>   then, simply copy the important files or all files from the internal &
>   external storage directory to your PC.